# autolayout equal width constraints

Tags: ios

I'm working on implementing a custom graph view.  The design calls for the graph to have a margin of 11 pts on the left and the right, there are 25 blocks of equal width, and the spacing between the blocks is 2.  Not surprisingly this lays out and looks pretty much perfect on iPhone 5s and below. Using autolayout the system correctly finds that each block should be 10x10.

[image]

Things break down however when moving to the 6 and 6+.  For instance on the 5 some frames are calculated with a width 12 and 12.5.  This is what I get from the 6.

[image]

By manually doing the math and applying the ratio of the new screen sizes the widths don't come out to be integers but what autolayout comes up with is pretty far off.  I have some ideas on how to work around this but I'm not quite sure how to do it.  Here is the code that is laying out my 25 columns:

var columns = Array()

```
    var lastAddedColumn: UIView?
    for index in 0...numberOfColumns - 1 {
        let column = GraphColumn(frame: CGRectZero)
        column.numberOfRectangles = 10
        column.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.addSubview(column)
        columns.append(column)

        if let lastColumn = lastAddedColumn {
            self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[v1]-2-[v2]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros, metrics: nil, views: dictionaryOfNames(lastColumn,column)))
            self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: column, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: lastColumn, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        }
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[v1]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros, metrics: nil, views: dictionaryOfNames(column)))

        lastAddedColumn = column
    }

    let firstColumn = columns.first!
    let lastColumn = columns.last!

    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstColumn, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 1))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: lastColumn, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: self, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: -1))
```

The approach I'm using is to loop from 1-25 creating a column each time.  That column is pinned 2 pts to the right of the column before it and given a width equal to the one before as well.  Finally I pin the first and last to the left and right of the superview.  The superview is added to the scene via the storyboard and is pinned 11 pts to the left and right of the superview.

What I think might work is to have the margins be flexible but I'm unsure of how to accomplish this.  I tried lowering the 11 pt let and right priorities and using less than or equal but that didn't work. Really what I'm trying to get autolayout to do is do the equal width thing and if it's unable to find equal widths then it should push out the margins until can do so.  I think whats holding me up is that the system is reporting that it can satisfy the constraints when in reality it can't.

Comment: It would be easier to write a custom UIView subclass that draws whatever you want using Core Graphics.

Comment: the columns themselves are drawn via core graphics.  Calculating the correct sizes is what autolayout is supposed to be good at but isn't working so hot in this situation.